# Fundamenta data type assignment operator with temporary objects

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello so i am trying to understand what is going on under the hood.

```
int* puter;
puter = std::make_unique<int>(50).get();
if(puter) { std::cout << *puter << std::endl; }
```

At first i thought the puter should be a dangling ptr because temporary unique_ptr from make_unique would be destroyed along with the allocated resource. But that is not the case.
After a while i could understand that it might not happen if the unique_ptr resource was move assigned to puter.
But the real question is. When should i assume things will get move asigned from temporary? Is there a rule to it? Should i just use release method for assurance in such cases?

Comment: "*But that is not the case.*" - How do you know?

Comment: It is the case and your code invokes *undefined behavior* - it may "work correctly" on your machine, but it is in fact broken

Comment: I know because the print std::cout is correct. If things are as @UnholySheep say then i am satisfied with that answers. I was only wondering if there is some standard covering that. Gonna wait for more answer

Comment: Well, on ideone the `std::cout` is not correct: https://ideone.com/yhDwtx - something you could have investigated yourself

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this actually triggers undefined behaviors.

Your original thought is exactly what happened

> At first i thought the puter should be a dangling ptr because temporary unique_ptr from make_unique would be destroyed along with the allocated resource

Thus,

```
if(puter) { std::cout << *puter << std::endl; }
```

causes undefined behaviors -- You don't know what is there, different compilers and machines can have different results(e.g. can be 50, can be 0, can be nullptr, or some garbage values...)

> But the real question is. When should i assume things will get move asigned from temporary? Is there a rule to it? Should i just use release method for assurance in such cases?

It depends if the type/class support move semantics(i.e. have move constructor/move assignment operator defined). If not, it's the same as copying.

In this case, int* is a primitive type, and primitive types do not have move constructor/assignment, so assign a temporary will not be move assign.

On the other hand, if you assign a temporary std::vector to another std::vector, move assignment will be called because std::vector class has a well-defined move assignment operator(and a move constructor). e.g.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v = std::vector<int>{1,2,3}; //RHS is a temporary object, so it will call the vector's move assignment operator
```